# Why cannot I save edits in ArcMap with geodatabase in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, objectid, arcmap

I create new object in ArcMap with geodatabase in SQL Server. Once I save edits I get the error:

> Unable to save edits. Underlying DBMS error [] Violation of primary
> key constraint "R148_pk". Impossible insert duplicate key into object
> "dbo.Table_1".

I noticed value of OBJECTID of creating object already exists in table of attributes.
What to do?

I set values of Indent and Seed to 1 for OBJECTID field. Though by default ArcMap doesn't set these values. I applied tools `DIAGNOSE VERSIONED TABLES` and `REPAIR VERSIONED TABLES`.
All that didn't help.

Comment: Really no answer at my question? May be the reason is in other?